# Reading value from a form using Java Spring Controller

Tags: java, html, spring, post, controller

I am facing a problem trying to receive the value of my [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA9eW.png). This value will be used I'll use to refresh the same page where I am using that value like a filter (filtering by city):

```
            <form action="/todoslosusuarios" modelAttribute="TodosLosUsuarios">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ciudad</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ciudad="ciudad"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr rowspan="2">
                        <td><input type="submit"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

The problem is that is not working:

So, that means that I am not reading correctly the value.

Here is my Controller code:

```
 @Controller
public class ExtraerTodosLosUsuariosRegistrado {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todoslosusuarios", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String ExtraerTodosLosUsuariosRegistrados(Model model) throws ParseException {

        tablausuario tu = new tablausuario();
        ArrayList<usuario> user = tu.listausuarios();
        Collections.sort(user, (o1, o2) -> o2.getCreatedAt().compareTo(o1.getCreatedAt())); //tabla ordenada

        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", user);

        return "ExtraerTodosLosUsuariosRegistrados";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/todoslosusuarios", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String ciudad(Model model, @RequestBody("ciudad") String ciudad) {
        tablausuariofilterbycity tufc = new tablausuariofilterbycity();
        ArrayList<usuario> userbycity = tufc.listausuariosfiltradosporciudad(ciudad);

        model.addAttribute("TodosLosUsuarios", userbycity);
        return "ExtraerTodosLosUsuariosRegistrados";
    }

}
```

And here is my HTML "ExtraerTodosLosUsuariosRegistrados"

```
 <div class="container">
            <h2>Listado de usuarios </h2> 
            <p th:text=" ${TodosLosUsuarios.size()} "></p>    


            <form action="/test" modelAttribute="TodosLosUsuarios">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ciudad</td>
                        <td><input type="text" ciudad="ciudad"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr rowspan="2">
                        <td><input type="submit"></input></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>

            <table class="table table-bordered" sortable>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>Teléfono</th>
                        <th>Día creado</th>
                        <th>Edad</th>
                        <th>Confirmado</th>
                        <th>Promocion</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody  th:each="usuariosTotales: ${TodosLosUsuarios}" >
                    <tr>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getNombre()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getEmail()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getPhoneNunmber()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getCreatedAt()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getEdad()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getConfirmationCode()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getPromotions()} " ></td>
                        <td th:text=" ${usuariosTotales.getAddress()} " ></td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Can someone help me to see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: try to replace ciudad="ciudad" by name="ciudad".

Answer (score 0):

the string is probably in the body of the request because you are using POST. But you are trying to read it as a request parameter from the url. Try changing the `@RequestParam(value = ciudad)` to `@RequestBody`

Comment: I did what you propose but seems like nothing happened

Comment: Hm strange. Did you wrote `@RequestBody()` or `@RequestBody("ciudad")` like in your post above? My suggestion is to use only `@RequestBody` without further parameters. In your actual code snippet above is also another parameter in the method. If you are just sending a single string within your post request the first parameter named `Model`will always be null. Spring can only map the `Model`if it's present in the body of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Open web browser console (F12) and take a look at the real HTTP request executed from the client (browser) to the server (your `/todoslosusuarios` expectedly). Then change the client or server to the expected interaction.

Use it for every similar case with client - server HTTP interaction